# Writing dynamic frame to s3 based on partition column but colon(:) symbol is being replaced by %3a

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

The partition column is a string but it contains time as well till seconds.
This is the partition column, so based on this i am writing the dynamic frame back to s3 but instead of : in time it is showing up %3a which is causing issues while querying through athena and all.